# Native interfaces in codenameone,

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am trying to execute my native code in Android and i am getting endless exceptions.I am trying to launch the native dialer and call a number withouth pressing the call button on the dialer.Please help and provide a full working code,here is what i have

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("*151*1*1*0779083353*2*1#"));
Activity activity = new Activity();
activity.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Native Interface code:

```
public class NativeAccessImpl { 
    public void load() { 
       final CodenameOneActivity activity = (CodenameOneActivity) AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(); 
    } 
    public void payEcocash() { 
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("*151*1*1*0779083353*2*1#")); 
        Activity activity = new Activity(); 
        activity.startActivity(callIntent); 
    } 
} 

t.start(); 

public boolean isSupported() { 
    return true; 
} 
}
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't show how you implemented the native interface and the exception you're getting. We can help you fix your code and suggest something that works, not write your code for you.

Comment: public class NativeAccessImpl {
 public void load() {
        final CodenameOneActivity activity = (CodenameOneActivity) AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
    }
    public void payEcocash() {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("*151*1*1*0779083353*2*1#"));
                Activity activity = new Activity();
                activity.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

}

Comment: What are the exceptions you're getting? Did you add import statements for Intent, Uri and Activity? I believe you're testing on Android device connected to ddms?

Comment: An internal application erro occured:java.lang.RuntimeExeception:Only one Looper may be created per thread.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your native code in:

```
com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       // your code goes here
   }
}
```

This will effectively move your code to the Android native event dispatch thread which most Android code expects.